# I can't zoom in more to my mesh

Tags: 3d-view

For some reason, I can't zoom in more. I'm on mac so i press cmd scroll but i can't zoom in. I can zoom out slowly but not in. Also, when i move my view (not sure if it is the right term), it goes way too fast, a slight scroll and it moves a lot. Also, when i use the hand to move, it goes EXTREMELy slowly

Edit i think it's because i only zoom, so there's a point where it can zoom in anymore.

Edit 2: I fixed it by toggling lock to object

[image: Even if i press cmd scroll, it doesn't move]

Comment: May be your object is too small.

Comment: Before, it was correct, but something happened and it zoom out a lot. Last thing i remember doing is shift c